# Stitch together multiple QPixmaps

Tags: qt, qpixmap

I'm looking for a method, no matter how roundabout, to horizontally stitch together three pixmaps into one (ie 20x20 + 20x20 + 20x20 -> 60x20). If it helps any, what I actually have is three png resources and I need to join them together and return a QIcon. Anyone any suggestions on routes to take?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method: You create a new QPixmap with the desired size and paint the 3 pixmaps into this pixmap (QPixmap is a QPaintDevice)

Answer (score 0):

For just what you said, you don't even need to do it in Qt. Why don't you just use any image editor to stitch the 3 images together? Sorry this may not answer your question on Qt but hope this solves your problem.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. The images change through the life of the program, and I don't want to stitch together all permutations!